# how to get code alignment in popup window

Tags: html, css

This code copy code functionality.when am click on copycode then it displayed code in the popup window it displayed code but align is in only one line...i have the proper alignment....[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJYgO.png) 
my code displays bellow with output screens please anyone suggest me for popup alignment ..

php code

```
<?php 
    $editorDesc = '<pre class="prettyprint tryit linenums">'. htmlspecialchars(isset($outTryEditorTableInfo[$s]['editor_description']) ? $outTryEditorTableInfo[$s]['editor_description'] : '').'</pre>';
    $finalResult = '<div class="ccsp-example" id="contentdiv" itemprop="articleBody" >'.$editorDesc.$tryItHereBtn.'</div><br/>'.$tryittask;
?>
```

css

```
<style>
 ol li {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: list;
    position: relative;
}

ol li:after {
    content: counter(list)"\00a0 \00a0 " ;
    border-right:1px solid #aeaeae;
    position: absolute;
    left: -2.5em;
    width:4%;
    text-align: right;
} 

</style>
```

js

```
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/google/code-prettify/master/loader/run_prettify.js?autoload=true&amp;skin=sunburst&amp;lang=css" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">//<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () { processCodeBlocks.Initialise('#contentdiv'); });
$(function (){
       $('.oauth').click(function () {
           $this = $(this);
           href = $this.attr('href');
           var myWindow = window.open(href, 'popup',
                       'width=800,height=600,location=0,menubar=0,resizeable=0,scrollbars=0,toolbar=0');
           myWindow.focus();
           var timer = setInterval(function () {
                           if (myWindow.closed) {
                               clearInterval(timer);
                               // window.location.reload(); // May do a POST reload, shows a warning
                               window.location = window.location; // force a GET reload
                           }
                       }, 200);
           return false;
       });
   });

</script>
```

Comment: use a <div> to englobe this text, and set its max size as you want. it must work. If not, reply and lets see what is happening. Also provide html code where you print it.

Comment: I want the code by pre tag

Comment: PRE tag must be used with fixed-width according to W3C.